# Many shortcuts don't work in Blender 2.8. Are these bugs?

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, shortcut

In blender 2.8 it looks like all the 0-9 keys were remapped to numpad only. Wondering why the viewpoint changes could not be done, I customized the keys back to my upper row or digit keys 0-9, because I have Apple keyboard without the numpad.

Even then the shortcuts don't work as expected. Changing the viewpoint using 0 thru 9 keys only works in Edit and Sculp Mode and only sometimes. What is the logic behind, I would like to know.

When in camera view, the shortcut **Shift+F** for free move does not work.

Also **CRTL(or CMD) + ALT + 0**  shortcut does not work.

These are these I discovered after an hour of messing around with Blender 2.8. Are these actually bugs or features? Anybody can chip in? I was used to 2.79 behavior.

Comment: Looks like the flying mode is enabled by Shift+~ now

Answer (score 4):

> CRTL(or CMD) + ALT + 0 shortcut does not work

Edit > Preferences window > Input tab : check Emulate Numpad

> Many shortcuts don't work in Blender 2.8. Are these bugs?

Not bugs.You can find the new shortcuts in,

Edit > Preferences window > Keymap

Annoying at first but I get used to it quickly.

Blender 2.8 is a big change and more "industry" compliant, for example:

- left click for selection (instead of right click)
- Space bar for Play/pause
- F3 for search, etc

[image]

Comment: hey, good answer.  However, I would like to know the answer for the free move.  You know the answer to that?

Comment: what do you call free move?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @shneo . The free move is my thinking is when you are in the view where you are looking through the camera and now you want to use arrow keys to reposition it and "fly" through the scene using arrow keys. This used to work using Shift+F shortcut, but not anymore.

Comment: I think I found the answer, it used to be Shift+F now it is Shift+~

Comment: Yes, you can find it with "fly" or "walk" in the keymap name search box.